# A mechanism that modifies the sine wave so it is flattened at its peaks

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

Piston displacement as a function of time produces a sine wave.
I need to modify the motion so the time the piston spends at both the bottom of the stroke and the top of the stroke are extended.
The motion curve would approximate a clipped audio wave.

The attached image shows three motions.

The "Desired function" maybe too harsh so I imagine a hybrid between this and the modified dine may be better for smooth mechanical operation.

So I am searching for a mechanism (a mechanical arrangement) that can produce this.

I am aware this can be achieved with a cam and various engaging and disengaging mechanisms, but these are not ideal solutions.
I am imagining a solution of rods and levers not that dissimilar to Walschaerts valve gear.

Comment: The attached image?

Comment: With (normal) crankshaft offset, piston displacement is NOT a sin wave. Crankshaft offset is the same as a cam. Normal engines use crankshaft offset to adjust the piston time-displacement relationship.

Comment: Maybe the junction was a bit obtuse.  You did not attach an image!